# Popover is not working- JS is not loaded when initialized from controller

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, popover

I have list of data in a table and provided a popover. Like when the pointer hovers to that image, it will pop the body of that data. It was working before I separated that view. I'm using yii.

This is my code for the table:

```
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($page_data['data_list']as $data_from_controller_key => $data_from_controller){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" . . . .><?php echo $data_from_controller['title'] ?></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <div rel="popover" data-trigger="hover"  
                     data-placement="left" data-content="<?php echo $data_from_controller['content'] ?>" >
                    <a class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-search"></i></a> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

The popover was working when this view was still a part of my `index.php`. Then I transferred this to another view and the next thing I knew, the popover did not work.

[UPDATE]

So I guess the problem is not in here. It is in my JS loading.
My JS's were not loaded in this view. Just like what happened to my `datatables.js`.
I tried putting the JS in this view by doing this at the bottom part to apply the JS since initializing it from the controller won't do any good:

```
    <script>
            $('table#listdata').dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'dt_header'<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'clear'f>>r>t<'dt_footer'<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>>",
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] }
                ],
                "bStateSave": true
        }).columnFilter();
    </script>
```

My new question is what is/are the reasons why my JS was not loaded/initialized?

Comment: Why are you using tow `$`? `$$data_from_controller`

Comment: oh, it's just a copy paste mistake..there you go...i edited it already

Comment: from your code I think you are using bootstrap, is that right?

Comment: yes. and i've already called initialized that in the controller

Answer (score 0):

In many ways you can load js snippet.

way 1:
You can write this snippets at the bottom of the main file of theme. i.e. before `</body>
</html>` tag.

way 2:

You can include custom js file at bottom of the main file of theme. i.e. check the following code:

- if you use Yii default theme:

---

`<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/assets/js/custom.js"></script>`

- if you use custom theme:

---

`<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/assets/js/custom.js"></script>`

Then, write the snippets in a function of custom.js file i.e.

```
function tableSorter(){

$('table#listdata').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'dt_header'<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'clear'f>>r>t<'dt_footer'<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>>",
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] }
    ],
    "bStateSave": true
}).columnFilter();
}
```

Now call the function for specific controller or specific action or specific view. At your stage, you should call function for specific view, just open your required view file and write the following code top of the file:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('tablesorter', "
$(function() { tableSorter();});
");
```

I use the Way 2. Please try. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because you have to state your script after the document is ready, that's your mistake

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('table#listdata').dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'dt_header'<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'clear'f>>r>t<'dt_footer'<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>>",
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] }
                ],
                "bStateSave": true
        }).columnFilter();
});
```

Comment: with this fix, i can put it back to datatables.js?